# Console output appearing for one millisecond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console

I'm working with jQuery and I have implemented a button click handler. To test, I have been setting a console output with the contents "test". However, when clicking on the button, the output appears in the console, but only for a brief moment before disappearing again. That repeats every time the button is clicked.

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#go").click(function () {
    console.log("test");
});
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
         <button id="go" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
</form>
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the button submits the form and reloads the entire page in your browser. Cancel the default action of this button by returning `false` from your `click` handler if you want to stay on the same page and continue executing some javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#go").click(function () {
        console.log("test");
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you do not cancel the default action, the browser will simply redirect away leaving no time for any javascript stuff to run.

Comment: That fixed it, although it worked fine with another project of mine that uses the same infrastructure. Wierd.

Comment: No, this couldn't have worked fine. Maybe you used an `<input type="button">` in this other project of yours which obviously is not the same thing as a submit button for a form and which doesn't actually submit the form. It's pretty easy to see what's happening. Just open the network tab of your javascript debugging console and look whether there's an HTTP request sent to the server after clicking on the button.

Comment: Could it perhaps be because of the form that this was wrapped into?

Comment: What difference does it make? If you want to cancel the default action of some handler you should return false from it. Otherwise you are risking to encounter the kind of problems you are currently having.

Comment: You're right there. Well, it's time to wait before I can accept your answer ;)